# How to enforce Pydantic error raising for wrong generic types

Tags: python, python-3.x, pydantic, typing

Below you can see my code

```
from pydantic import BaseModel
from typing import TypeVar, Generic

T = TypeVar('T')

class GenericItem(BaseModel, Generic[T]):
    item: T

# Examples of using GenericItem
string_item = GenericItem[str](item="example")
int_item = GenericItem[int](item=42)

# This will raise a validation error because 'item' is expected to be of type 'int'
try:
    invalid_item = GenericItem[int](item="invalid")
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Validation error: {e}")
```

I want to use a generic value `T` and I have a field `item` of that value.

When I create `GenericItem[int](item="invalid")` it should throw an error, because the input should be `int`, but it is an `str`. Yet, no error shows up.

How can I make that possible, such that in this case it would just accept input of the specified type `T`?

Comment: I run the code, but it works well. It raises `Input should be a valid integer, unable to parse string as an integer [type=int_parsing, input_value='invalid', input_type=str]` with a validation error. What is Pydantic version you use?

Comment: @SpikeLee many thanks for getting back to me. I am using pydantic[email]==1.10.12 (sadly, I cannot upgrade it due to a version conflict with another package).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it was the intended feature in v1.10.x.

As I commented, after V2, that works fine. But in v1.10x, you need to use `GenericModel`

```py
from pydantic.generics import GenericModel  # Import `GenericModel` instead of `BaseModel`
from typing import TypeVar, Generic

T = TypeVar('T')

class GenericItem(GenericModel, Generic[T]):  # use `GenericModel`
    item: T

# Examples of using GenericItem
string_item = GenericItem[str](item="example")
int_item = GenericItem[int](item=42)

# This will raise a validation error because 'item' is expected to be of type 'int'
try:
    invalid_item = GenericItem[int](item="invalid")
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Validation error: {e}")
```

Run it; you might have got

```py
Validation error: 1 validation error for GenericItem[int]
item
  value is not a valid integer (type=type_error.integer)
```

Ref: https://docs.pydantic.dev/1.10/usage/models/#generic-models